# svn update with ! and ? as status of files

Tags: svn

I have a bunch of files on an svn that have a status of ! and ?. I've read the documentation and know that this means the file is missing or unversioned. My question is if I run svn update will it add the file to my local copy of the directory or will it be removed from the repository?

Answer (score 1):

A file with a `?` is unversioned, if you do an `svn up`, nothing happens to it.

A file with a `!` is missing, if you do an `svn up`, it will be downloaded again from the repository. If you want to remove that file from the repository, don't just do `rm file`, but `svn rm file`.

Answer (score 0):

Files which are showing as ? are not under version control. Eg: a new file you have created in your working copy. You have to use "svn add" followed by "svn commit" to checkin these files to SVN. Once you use svn add, it will show "+" icon instead of "?". svn update will not have any impact on these files.

Files showing "!" are files you have changed/modified in your working copy. An "svn update"  in your working copy may or may not result in conflicts, depending on whether the same files are modified both in your working copy and in SVN (by some other users). You can refer the below link on how to resolve conflicts in svn:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html

Files which are deleted from SVN will be shown as *. These files will be restored with svn update. You can refer the below image for common svn status symbols:

[image]